# What are edge loops and front edges and how to select them?

Tags: modeling

Can't seem to figure out what i should do, a person said on one of my answers i should select the front edges and whole loops and i don't know much about blender since im still new. He then said before using the bevel tool there are 4 modes and you can switch between them using 'm'. Also when using whole loops and front edges is there a way to select them all?

Comment: wow, too many questions here, could you please ask one question and help to understand what you mean, with screenshots for example? Plus you'll find a lot of tutorials about all these topics: Edge loops, faces selection, bevel...

Comment: Hold alt when selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

The selected edges in the picture I attached are edge loops. To select all the way around the loop, hold alt and click. For the bevel tool, just hit control b or apply a bevel modifier in the modifiers panel on the right.
[image]